# HWIOAuthBundle's PathUserResponse errors

Tags: symfony, oauth

Almost everything's working great in my project, except that when I log in (using facebook) with a user that has no correspondence in my database (FOSUserBundle), I get redirected to /registration/{id} only to get an error:

`The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Entity\User, but is an instance of class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\PathUserResponse to an instance of Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Entity\User.`

I also had to overwrite connect.confirm.html.twig to delete the following lines:

```
{% if userInformation.profilePicture is not empty %}
    <img src="{{ userInformation.profilePicture }}" />
{% endif %}
```

It said PathUserResponse had no profilePicture method. My guess is I should not be using PathUserResponse, but I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind people of HWI/OAuth-Bundle have fixed the issue. I thought I was doing something wrong, but those were actually known bugs.